# Detener animación javascript. Balloons birthday

Tags: javascript, animación

Buen día. Encontré una animación genial, como la que utiliza twitter que salen globos en tu perfil cuando es tu "cumpleaños", que se llama balloons birthday. Quiero utilizarla en una web, es super fácil de implementar y funciona de maravilla, pero el único problema es que no se cómo hacer que se detenga.

El github de la animación es este: https://github.com/erdoganbavas/web-practices/tree/master/bday-balloons

Por lo que entiendo el bucle se repite al infinito. Pero yo quiero que pasado un tiempo la animación se detenga y sólo vuelva activarse si se recarga la página. He probado introducir setTimeOut en algunas partes del código, pero hasta ahora nada, y es que no se mucho de javascript.

Pongo el código completo, desarrollado por Erdoğan Bavaş https://github.com/erdoganbavas

```
const bdayBallons = (function(){
    const density = 7; // concurrent balloon count
    const balloons = []; 
    const colors = ['yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'red'];

    const stringElement = document.createElement("div");
    stringElement.classList.add("string");

    for (let i = 0; i < density; i++) {
        const element = document.createElement("div");
        element.classList.add("balloon");
        element.classList.add(randomColor());

        element.append(stringElement.cloneNode());
        document.body.append(element);
        
        setTimeout(() => {
            releaseBalloon(element);
        }, (i * 2000) + random(500, 1000));
    }


    function randomColor() {
        return colors[ random(0, colors.length) ];
    }

    function random (min, max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min)) + min;
    }

    function releaseBalloon(balloon) {
        const delay = random(100, 1000);
        const x = random(-99, -30); // random x value to fly
        const y = random(-99, -30); // random y value to fly

        const sequence = [{
            offset: 0,
            transform: `rotateZ(45deg) translate(0, 0)`
        }];


        // random fly direction
        if(random(0,2) === 0) {
            // first fly up to top left

            // left distance to keep balloon in view
            balloon.style.left = `${-1*x}vw`;

            sequence.push({
                offset: x/-200,
                transform: `rotateZ(45deg) translate(${x}vw, 0)`
            });
            sequence.push({
                offset: (x+y)/-200,
                transform: `rotateZ(45deg) translate(${x}vw, ${y}vh)`
            });
            sequence.push({
                offset: (-100+y)/-200,
                transform: `rotateZ(45deg) translate(-100vw, ${y}vh)`
            });
        } else {
            // fist fly up to right top

            sequence.push({
                offset: y/-200,
                transform: `rotateZ(45deg) translate(0, ${y}vh)`
            });
            sequence.push({
                offset: (x+y)/-200,
                transform: `rotateZ(45deg) translate(${x}vw, ${y}vh)`
            });
            sequence.push({
                offset: (-100+x)/-200,
                transform: `rotateZ(45deg) translate(${x}vw, -100vh)`
            });
        }

        // last move is common
        sequence.push({
            offset: 1,
            transform: `rotateZ(45deg) translate(-100vw, -100vh)`
        });

        const balloonAnimation = balloon.animate(sequence, {
            duration: 15000,
            delay: delay
        });


        balloonAnimation.onfinish = () => { releaseBalloon(balloon) }
    }
})();
```

Comment: No es un bucle. `releaseBalloon` se engancha a si misma sobre la finalización de la animación de un globo (iniciada por esa misma función): `balloonAnimation.onfinish = () => { releaseBalloon(balloon) }`. Solución simple: Ponele un flag y esa línea metela dentro de un if. `if (! flagTerminar) {balloon.onfinish ...}`. El flag cambialo con un botón o con un timer, o lo que quieras. Así una vez terminada esa animación, la función no se ejecuta más.

Comment: Me parece buena explicación, pero no logro que funcione. Ej. function timeout() {setinterval(timeout, 2000); } if(!timeout) { balloonAnimation.onfinish = () => { releaseBalloon(balloon) }} No se si en todo caso utilizar algo como finish() pero ya busqué ejemplos y nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extiendo un poco lo que puse en los comentarios con código. Esto la detiene cambiando el flag con un timeout.

Me disculpo, pero prometo que si te sirve, mañana cuando tenga más tiempo edito la respuesta para formatearla mejor:

```javascript
 var finalizar = false;

 setInterval(()=>{
     finalizar = true;
 }, 2000);

/* abajo es tu código con una única modificación, la marco */

 const bdayBallons = (function(){
     const density = 7; // concurrent balloon count
     const balloons = []; 
     const colors = ['yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'red'];

     const stringElement = document.createElement("div");
     stringElement.classList.add("string");

     for (let i = 0; i < density; i++) {
         const element = document.createElement("div");
         element.classList.add("balloon");
         element.classList.add(randomColor());

         element.append(stringElement.cloneNode());
         document.body.append(element);
         
         setTimeout(() => {
             releaseBalloon(element);
         }, (i * 2000) + random(500, 1000));
     }


     function randomColor() {
         return colors[ random(0, colors.length) ];
     }

     function random (min, max){
         return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min)) + min;
     }

     function releaseBalloon(balloon) {
         console.log("liberando globo");
         const delay = random(100, 1000);
         const x = random(-99, -30); // random x value to fly
         const y = random(-99, -30); // random y value to fly

         const sequence = [{
             offset: 0,
             transform: `rotateZ(45deg) translate(0, 0)`
         }];


         // random fly direction
         if(random(0,2) === 0) {
             // first fly up to top left

             // left distance to keep balloon in view
             balloon.style.left = `${-1*x}vw`;

             sequence.push({
                 offset: x/-200,
                 transform: `rotateZ(45deg) translate(${x}vw, 0)`
             });
             sequence.push({
                 offset: (x+y)/-200,
                 transform: `rotateZ(45deg) translate(${x}vw, ${y}vh)`
             });
             sequence.push({
                 offset: (-100+y)/-200,
                 transform: `rotateZ(45deg) translate(-100vw, ${y}vh)`
             });
         } else {
             // fist fly up to right top

             sequence.push({
                 offset: y/-200,
                 transform: `rotateZ(45deg) translate(0, ${y}vh)`
             });
             sequence.push({
                 offset: (x+y)/-200,
                 transform: `rotateZ(45deg) translate(${x}vw, ${y}vh)`
             });
             sequence.push({
                 offset: (-100+x)/-200,
                 transform: `rotateZ(45deg) translate(${x}vw, -100vh)`
             });
         }

         // last move is common
         sequence.push({
             offset: 1,
             transform: `rotateZ(45deg) translate(-100vw, -100vh)`
         });

         const balloonAnimation = balloon.animate(sequence, {
             duration: 15000,
             delay: delay
         });

         /* acá releaseBalloon se relanza únicamente si finalizar es true */
         balloonAnimation.onfinish = () => { finalizar || releaseBalloon(balloon) }
         /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^^^^^^^^^^ */
     }
 })();
```

Comment: Ya lo probé y modifiqué de varias maneras siguiendo tu idea y otros ejemplos, pero no se detiene. Le mandé un tweet al creador y lo único que me dijo fue "balloonAnimation var is a web animation instance soyo may use pause and play methods on it".Estaba pensando que en lugar de usar "var finalizar" podemos usar "var balloonAnimation". voy a probar algo así

Comment: El código tal cual lo puse funciona para mí usando el CSS original y un HTML básico. Por la tarde lo subo a GitHub para que lo puedas ver.

Comment: Oh ya. claro que si funciona tu código. Lo que pasa que yo había modificado la densidad, si es un valor muy alto entra en contrariedad entre el tiempo y el número de globos que se sueltan. Es cosa de ajustar entre el tiempo que finaliza la animación, el número de globos que se sueltan y la rapidez con la que se sueltan. Mil gracias!